# how to put all social media sites in one share button sprite kit / objective-c

Tags: uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, social-networking

Now i have figured out how to post score to a social media by clicking one button, but i see some apps have a share button that combines all the social media sites. when you click the share button, it offers several social media icons for you to choose.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/#classes

Comment: @sangony I think I should use UIActivityViewController